# Is there anyway to mimic or mock a Linux command line in a Java JUnit test

Tags: java, linux, unit-testing, junit

I have been working recently on a JUnit test for an application.

This application is executed in a Linux environment and the arguments, options and other critical information is incorporated into the command line which is then sent to the Java code.

I have been trying to find different ways to test certain aspects of the application using JUnit 3.8.1, but I have run across some issues with methods that deal with the command line and arguments passed from it.

My question: Is there anyway to set up a mock or psuedo Linux command line prompt or even try hard code a command line that is fed to the test methods?

I have been researching for a while but I can't find anything that really answers my question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can call `TestMain.main(args)` directly, you don't need a command line to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main method is a method like any other, so you can unit test it like any other, passing through an array od strings as the command line arguments.

But I don't do this. Instead, I have the main method create a `Program` object and delegate to that object. I unit test this `Program` class. This is so I can mock other aspects of the environment: the constructor for the `Program` class is passed a string array for the command line arguments, a `Properties` object for the system properties, a `Map` for the environment variables, and so on. I'm left with a small main method that I don't unit test, and a `Program` class I can thoroughly unit test.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if ist is that what you search. Bit to execute commando linea commands from java, you can use ExecuteShellCommand.

```
   ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();           
     String output = obj.executeCommand(command);
```